# Can Hexo generate PDF file?

Tags: node.js, pdf, documentation, hexo

Is there a plugin or some option that instead of using "Hexo generate" static website, I can export pages into pdf? ( I'm using Hexo for tech dox )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generate to a static website firstly, then open with chrome, then print the page and choose to save as PDF.